# How do I refresh a DIV content every 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to refresh a certain div to refresh every 30 seconds. There are others div's on my HTML page, but they do not need to refresh.

The idea is to reload/refresh the div itself.

I have tried this script, but can not get it to work.
Here is my HTML and Javascript code
The path in my html file is

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./difcol.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Here are my css file for refresh.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $("refresh").load(window.location.href + " refresh");
    }, 30000);
  });
</script>

<div id="refresh" class="sp-container">
  <div class="sp-content">
    <div class="sp-globe"></div>
    <h2 class="frame-1">1</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-2">2</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-3">3</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-4">4</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-5">5</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-6">6</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-7">
      <span>a,</span>
      <span>b,</span>
      <span>c</span>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow');

body {
  background: #310404 url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wOvQAhzWCrM/maxresdefault.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1.main, p.demos {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.sp-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}
.sp-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.sp-container h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  font-size: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
  -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
  -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
  animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
    font-size: 200px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
    font-size: 200px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
    font-size: 200px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
  font-size: 200px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
  animation-delay: 9s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
  font-size: 200px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay:12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-6 {
  font-size: 200px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 15s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-7 {
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  -ms-animation: none;
  animation: none;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-7 span {
  -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 18s backwards;
  -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 18s backwards;
  -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 18s backwards;
  animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 18s backwards;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-7 span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 21s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 21s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 21s;
  animation-delay: 21s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-7 span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.sp-globe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 282px;
  height: 273px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -137px 0 0 -141px;
 /* background: transparent url(http://web-sonick.zz.mu/images/sl/globe.png) no-repeat top left;*/
  -webkit-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
  -moz-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
  -ms-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
  animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  opacity: 0.3;
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
  -moz-transform: scale(5);
  -o-transform: scale(5);
  -ms-transform: scale(5);
  transform: scale(5);
}
.sp-circle-link {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #3f1616;
  font-size: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
  -moz-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
  -ms-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
  animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}
.sp-circle-link:hover {
  background: #85373b;
  color: #fff;
}
/**/

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  20%, 75% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transform: scale(5);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRotate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
/**/

@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  20%, 75% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -moz-transform: scale(5);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInRotate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
/**/

@keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  20%, 75% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
@keyframes blurFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInBack {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transform: scale(5);
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInRotate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of refreshing it? One way you can do is to clear the div and re-draw the content

Comment: try to add # (id) to your selector and you will be need to be more specific to that you are trying to re render

Comment: `$("refresh")` selects the `refresh` HTML element (i.e. `<refresh>`), but `$("#refresh")` selects the HTML element with an ID of "refresh" (i.e. `<div id="refresh">`)

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by 'refresh'? Do you just want to put the contents back to what they were when you first started or do you want to read in some info from an external source?

Answer (score 1):

You're lacking `#` in `$("refresh")` for referring to `refresh` id. The change should be

```
$("#refresh").load(window.location.href + " refresh");
```

*Note that I reduced the interval time to 1 second and put a log to show differences*

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $("#refresh").load(window.location.href + " refresh", function() { console.log("loaded") });
    }, 1000);
  });
</script>

<div id="refresh" class="sp-container">
  <div class="sp-content">
    <div class="sp-globe"></div>
    <h2 class="frame-1">1</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-2">2</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-3">3</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-4">4</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-5">5</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-6">6</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-7">
      <span>a,</span>
      <span>b,</span>
      <span>c</span>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nick Vu  Your code is nearly working, When I run it, it go thru the steps, then it take the words away, then it just keep blank and not starting again

Comment: in that case, you need to check your URL `window.location.href + " refresh"` has content or not. If it does not have any content, it will load nothing, @Hendrik

Comment: Nick Vu.  It is running on localhost C:\test. Not sure how to add it

Comment: Could you share your `refresh` code as well as that path file in your question too? That would help to narrow down where your problem is, @Hendrik

Comment: @ Nick vu. Did add it, hope it is what you are looking for

Comment: @Hendrik you want to refresh content or CSS? I'm not sure about what you want to achieve with these styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the contents of the div in a javascript variable once the page loads
then in your set interval function:
`document.getElementById('refresh').innerHTML = x;` :

```
<head>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById('refresh').innerHTML;

setInterval(function() {
     document.getElementById('refresh').innerHTML = x;
    }, 30000);
</script>
</head>
```